# Django QueryDict How to ensure that the "plus" does not disappear in the QueryDict?

Tags: python, django, urllib

How to ensure that the "plus" does not disappear in the QueryDict?

I am trying to parse the received get-query into a dict:

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

my_non_safe_string = "test=1+1" # This example, the string can be anything. (in GET query format)
QueryDict(my_non_safe_string)
out: <QueryDict: {'test': ['1 1']}>

my_safe_string = quote_plus("test=1+1") # 'test%3D1%2B1'
out: <QueryDict: {'test=1+1': ['']}>
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
<QueryDict: {'test=1+1': ['1+1']}>
```

Comment: I find it odd that you want `test=1+1` as key of the `QueryDict`, this makes it hard to "guess" what the key is where the expression is associated with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to percentage encode the plus, by use `quote_plus` you also encode the equal sign (`=`) and therefore the `QueryDict` can not parse it effectively:

```
my_safe_string = f'test={quote_plus("1+1")}'
```

this produces:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote_plus
>>> my_safe_string = f'test={quote_plus("1+1")}'
>>> QueryDict(my_safe_string)
<QueryDict: {'test': ['1+1']}>
```

If it is unclear if the key contains any characters that should be escaped, you can use:

```
key = 'test'
value = '1+1'
my_safe_string = f'{ quote_plus(key) }={ quote_plus(value) }'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```py
In [1]: from django.http import QueryDict

In [2]: from urllib.parse import quote_plus

In [3]: key = quote_plus("test=1+1")

In [4]: value = quote_plus("1+1")

In [5]: query_str = f"{key}={value}"

In [6]: QueryDict(query_str)
Out[6]: <QueryDict: {'test=1+1': ['1+1']}>
```